# Slur shape change

Tags: lilypond, engraving, slurs, lily-scheme

Using LilyPond, I am re-typesetting a score which uses an unusual symbol.  Essentially, it is a slur between two adjacent notes, but the slur is mirror-imaged around its longest dimension.  Essentially it is as if a slur above the staff were displayed below the staff instead.

I know how to use `\shape` to move this manually, but that requires careful adjustment for each individual slur.

I believe that the standard, below staff slur would work perfectly if I could generate a shape command using alterations to the automatically determined control points.  With four control points, one can create an imaginary line down the long axis of the quadrilateral, and mirror all four points around that axis.

1. I need to find out what the automatically determined control points *x* and *y* coordinates are, and where in the parsing of the LilyPond source they become defined.
2. I need to get an idea of how to write an additional Scheme function to take the original points and create a new slur command that will be an inverted slur.

Comment: What does the symbol mean? Could it be upside-down by mistake? If the score is written using computer software, depending on the application, it can be quite easy to make that mistake.

Comment: It is absolutely not a mistake.  The instrument is carillon, and the symbol is used to indicate two successive notes played with the same hand. Alternating hands is the norm, but will not always work. The score a duplicated autograph score by the arranger.

Comment: @CharlesNix I feel like an image of the source material would certainly help to better and easily understand what you're talking about. I'm not experienced with lilypond, but if I'm not mistaken, it should be relatively easy to create slurs using Bezier-based curves, you just need to understand how those curves are created.

Comment: @musicamante absolutely, a Bezier curve is what it needed.  My stumbling block is knowing 1) what the values of the variables containing the _automatically_ determined four Bezier control points are, and 2) when in the layout/typesetting sequence the determination of those points is made, i.e. what function does slur layout.  The standard slur is in the correct place, but the curve "bellies" away from the notes, whether the slur is above or below.  The slur I want to create is in exactly the same position, but curving the opposite direction.  If I had the control points, I could do it.